# Render quality suddenly changed?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

last week I tried rendering with low resolution quality. Then I switched to 'HDTV 1080p' preset and it rendered well for some time (rendering took cca 4 minutes per image).

Today I tried to render again. I've checked preview and it looks OK (preview takes up to 2 minutes to render), but when I click actual render button, it gives me a poor image with rendering time 0.25 seconds.

I don't remember changing any settings, but obviously something has changed? I cannot seem to find the reason.

Here is the preview:

[image]

Here is the final render:

[image]

Settings: (cycles render):

[image]

Help :(

Thanks in advance, Gregor

Comment: I think you should reduce your Samples at final render by uncheck the square sample at SAMPLING setting. You have too much samples (32400) as i see.

Comment: Thank you! This didn't solve the problem unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I have previously made a animation out of images in sequence editor. When I clicked render, the computer did not do any rendering, it simply loaded already rendered image.

I fixed this simply deleting all the time strips @ Video Sequence Editor. Now it does surely take up to 5 minutes for one frame to render. :)

Cheers for all the help!

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted ✅. That way it wont show up in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering your file in a different slot. Also check your lighting and resolution presets that might affect the render quality. It also might have problems with memory usage the last time you have rendered there was more memory usage blender used. this time its different

Comment: Hello, I tried all of the above. I have no idea what is going on. I set rendering on HD 1080p, but the quality is nowhere near. I've seen memory usage difference, but I don't have an explanation for that. The blender file is 580mb large, so it will be hard for me to upload it.